# Android HoloGraphic Theme

Tags: themes, android

I have an app that has minSdkVersion of 8 (Android 2.2). And I want to support my app in Tablet (Api Level 11 and above). I have implemented each UI for Tablet(for xlarge screen). 
Everyhing works and looks fine except Dialogs. Progressdialog , alertdialogs etc are so small.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

I read the instructions described at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html . Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. Dialogs are still small.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think it is related to this article [Displaying Alert Dialogs to 90 % of your screen size][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306503/how-to-make-an-alert-dialog-fill-90-of-srceen-size

Comment: Thanks, it works well. Now dialogs can expands vertically and horizontally. As I understand; default dialogs are small in Tablets, I should manually make them bigger, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The default UI for the Dialogs are of fixed size and they also depend upon the width and height of the screen. If I'm correct, They are positioned by the  Surface Manager.