# How do i set the width of a dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

im using this advice:
[How to make an alert dialog fill 90% of screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306503/how-to-make-an-alert-dialog-fill-90-of-srceen-size/6631310#6631310)

but i dont want it to set the height, just the width. i tried removing the fill parent to height, but it made it full parent anyway.

so how do i set the width only?

Answer (score 2):

```
getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,'yourHeightHere');
```

Comment: that function would only work for a single screen size. thx for help tho.

Comment: @Raz thanks man! 2 texasman1979 - why would it only work for single size? you can set it to "FILL_PARENT" or any height according to density