# Custom dialog height to match content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, customdialog

This is my custom dialog, there are some textboxs and two buttons.
I'm using a RelativeLayout on it.

I'd like the dialog size to match the content, not all that blank space under there.
I don't want to use explicit pixel heights (it's not good practice).

Another thing, there's a way to have some space between every view?

[image]

This is my XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="8pt"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_desc"
    android:textSize="8pt" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_place"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_date"
    android:textSize="8pt" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_place"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view"
    android:text="@string/btn_close" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_place"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
    android:text="@string/btn_edit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use MarginTop|MarginLeft|... for your second question. Measures in dp

Answer (score 4):

**First question**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

**Second question**

Plus use android:marginTop="5dp" if you want to separate a View from Top for 5 dp.
marginLeft|Right|Bottom are also available.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_place"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" <-----------------
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_date"
    android:textSize="8pt" />
```

By the way, if I were you, I'd nest some layouts to make order. You can have a general Relative Layout, then 2 linear layouts: one horizontal for TextViews and one vertical for Buttons. You can definely play with your editor and try to make the best appearance for your dialog.

**EDIT**

Try this one:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="prova"
                android:textSize="8pt"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="prova"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_place"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="prova"
                android:textSize="8pt" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_edit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
                android:text="btn_edit" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="btn_close" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've hard-coded the texts. The main idea is to use a big container layout in background, which is trasparent (`background=#0000`) and in top of that a layout in wrap_content containing your Views.

If this solution doesn't resolve your problem, I think you could edit height directly in your code. Try to relate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306503/how-to-make-an-alert-dialog-fill-90-of-screen-size)

Comment: The second is solved, but for the first one I tried to change both to wrap_content, but nothing seems to happen :/ Changing them in wrap_contet made the buttons overlap. Now it look like one button wide all the dialog.

Comment: It could be a little rough but.. why don't you try `android:paddingBottom="50dp"` in `<RelativeLayout` node? I've only seen using this on a linear layout (in that case, try to change your layout just to try it)

Comment: It doesn't work. Even with paddingBottom, the dialog keeps that height

Comment: Your innermost vertical LinearLayouts are unnecessary. One vertical LinearLayout containing TextViews and a horizontal LinearLayout is all that is necessary to reproduce the original layout.

Answer (score 0):

Set your relative layout's height to `wrap_content`.

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- More XML -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also be aware that `fill_parent` is deprecated for widths and heights.

You can add either margin (extra space outside a view) or padding (extra space inside a view) with `android:layout_margin` or `android:padding` respectively. There are also variants such as `layout_marginTop` that only apply to a specific side of the view.

Comment: I have change layout_width and layout_height like you said, but nothing changed :(

Comment: Is this being used in a DialogFragment?

Comment: I have my dialog_show XML, then in my java I use Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this); dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_show); and dialog.show();

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using a `RelativeLayout`? It looks like a `LinearLayout` might suffice. If you do switch, do you see the same behavior?

Comment: Can't believe it was really that simple. Using LinearLayout works! I used RelativeLayout for ToRightOf attributes, but I've just figured out it's better using nested LinearLayout with vertical and horizontal. Thx!