# How to make the popupWindow size 90% of the parent window or screen size in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity, popupwindow

I am currently trying to control the size of a popup in an activity. Actually, I would like to have it take a certain amount of the screen size : for e.g, 80% of the screen. I didn't succeed so far.

How can it be done with Android ? would it be possible to have its size relative to the screen or parent window size ?

Any help would be appreciated,
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an alert dialog fill 90% of screen size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306503/how-to-make-an-alert-dialog-fill-90-of-screen-size)

Comment: @CommonsWare yes but it didn't answer my question so ...

Comment: There are many answers on that question. Saying that "I didn't succeed so far" is not especially helpful. You might consider editing your question and explaining why every one of the answers on that question are insufficient for your needs.