# Change the width of the Dialog window of Android app dynamically

Tags: android, dialog

I am creating an Android application. In that application, I am using
a Dialog window to display HTML contents which come from the sever
side. I created the Dialog window using below method.

```
private void displayDialogWindow(String html) {

        // here I have created new dialog window
        dialog = new Dialog(cordova.getActivity(),
                android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar);
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations =
android.R.style.Animation_Dialog;
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);


        // creates a new webview to display HTML and attached to
dialog to display
        webview = new WebView(cordova.getContext());
        webview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.requestFocusFromTouch();

        final String mimeType2 = "text/html";
        final String encoding2 = "UTF-8";
        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType2, encoding2, "");
        dialog.setContentView(webview);

        // get the screen size of the device
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;

        // set appropriate sizes to the dialog window whether there is
side menu or not
        lp.copyFrom(dialog2.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = width ;
        lp.height = height - 100;
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp2);

        dialog.show();
    }
```

Using above method I could successfully create a Dialog window.

And I am creating the Dialog window using a Thread,

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() {

                displayDialogWindow(html);

            }
};
```

But after display the Dialog window once, I want to change the width
of the Dialog window dynamically. (eg. when I click on another button
of my app, the width of the window should be decreased and come to the
original width when another button is pressed).

Can any one help me to change the width of the Dialog window dynamically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10912076/826657 see this

Comment: @twntee I saw that, but it does not address my issue friend. I want to change it dynamically.

Comment: @harsh what about my answer? If you found another solution, please post it ;-) .

Answer (score 3):

I think that you have to "recreat" your dialog everytime you want to change it.
After *yourDialog.show()* method, you can insert this line:

```
yourDialog.getWindow().setLayout((6 * width)/7, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

This allow you to resize your Dialog window and it's content.
Of course **width** and **height** are the size of your screen.