# Dialog is shrinking even with all parent layout_width set as fill_parent

Tags: android, layout, dialog

Another weird behavior encountered here. This time my dialog is shrinking width wise inspite of setting  all parent layout's width as fill_parent. Here is the image...[image]

I have tried making it an activity with theme set as Dialog in manifest. Still it is behaving same. However it becomes normal as soon as I set layout_width for first TextView "User Agreement" as fill_parent. But I don't understand this behavior as it should not depend on TextView's width for its own width. Please tell me if there is any other efficient way to deal with these type of situations. My code for layout is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@layout/gradientback"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="User Agreement"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#B80303" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" >
    </View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxForTermsId"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#7B4302"
            android:text="I Agree The Terms &amp; Conditions" >
        </CheckBox>
```

This is not whole code for layout because I don't think it is needed...

The code for showing Dialog is as follows:

```
private void showAgreementBox() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Launcher.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.useragreement);
        dialog.setTitle("User Agreement");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        final TextView userAg = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textViewOfUserAg);
        final CheckBox checkUserAg = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxForTermsId);
        final Button continueB = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.continueB);
        checkUserAg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (checkUserAg.isChecked() == true) {
                    continueB.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    continueB.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });

        continueB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
                //checkForTrialPeriod(isUserRegisterd);
            }
        });

        Button cancelB = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelB);
        cancelB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: the word is "example" not "exemple"! :-)

Comment: @bofredo: What if I say it is Temple...:)

Comment: hehehe i was thinking on that too, but i choose the odds were against it ;)

Comment: but for real, i have the same issues with dialogFragments like yours too and i'm curious on the solution!

Comment: hmm....lets see if anyone else have faced this weirdo...:)

Comment: @VikramSingh post the code where you create the dialog.

Comment: @JaAd: added the code for dialog..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix the width of your parent layout

```
 android:layout_width="400dp"
```

fill_parent works for Activity xml but for dialogs you have to set the width.

If you are looking for a general solution **set an image as background** in the parent layout just like we place images in different drawable folders to support multiple screens.

You can also set width as full screen using

```
dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().width = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
```

**Why this behavior is shown by dialog** (quoting from [this post](https://android-developers.narkive.com/R7C0bEbn/dialog-cannot-fill-whole-screen#post4) by Dianne Hackborn)

> The dialog theme, as part of its nature, sets the top-level window
> layout to be WRAP_CONTENT.  You could try manually setting the Window
> layout width and height to FILL_PARENT [...]

Also took reference from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306503/how-to-make-an-alert-dialog-fill-90-of-screen-size).

Comment: I think he is looking for a more generic solution, that works on different devices..

Comment: I have already tried placing an image in background and it is solving the problem but I don't want to do that as it increase the size of my application. But the question is why it is depending on the width of my title textview and not any other layout or view...

Comment: Updated answer again.

Comment: Second half of your answer worked...thanks...+1 for information of dialog theme...:)

Answer (score 4):

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);
    getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

this worked for me .