# How to set the size in percentage of an alert dialog

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog

I've this xml file as layout for alert dialog

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/layout_root"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" >
      <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
      <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:textColor="#FFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I need the percentage and not dp value of size

Comment: may be you mean `android:weight` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an alert dialog fill 90% of screen size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306503/how-to-make-an-alert-dialog-fill-90-of-screen-size)

Comment: i need less than 90%... i need value around 60/70%