# Can't set size of AlertDialog Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

In the method `onOptionsItemSelectedMenu` I have a `AlertDialog.Builder` 
I am opening a WebView inside this AlertDialog.

However, I want to change the size of the AlertDialog.Builder, I want to change width and height according to my decision.I read a lot of questions here, but strangely nothing worked. Especially this article: [How to make an alert dialog fill 90% of screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306503/how-to-make-an-alert-dialog-fill-90-of-screen-size)
 How can I change the size of it ? I want to change it programmatically. I don't inflate any layout or anything else.

Here is my little code:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_inner_basics) {


            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            android.webkit.WebView wv = new WebView(this);
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
            alertDialog.setView(wv);
            alertDialog.show();


        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to resize a dialog after calling `Dialog.show()`. I usually create a new class extends from `AppCompatDialog` for dialog. In the bellow code, I override the `show()` method and put the `resizeDialog();` at the end of `show()` method.

```
public class LocationDialog extends AppCompatDialog {

    public LocationDialog(Activity activity) {
        super(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);

        initView();
    }

    private void initView(){
        // To get WebView from dialog_layout.xml
        // And showing website in this view
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();

        resizeDialog();
    }

    /**
     * To resize the size of this dialog
     */
    private void resizeDialog() {
        try {
            Window window = getWindow();

            if (activity == null || window == null) return;

            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

            int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

            window.setLayout((int) (width * 0.95), (int) (height * 0.85));
            window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));// make tranparent around the popup
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            ignore.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**dialog_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

In your activity, you should do:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_inner_basics) {
        LocationDialog dialog = new LocationDialog(Activity);
        dialog.show();
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will just try it but one question. What is `R.layout.dialog_layout` ? I don't have any layout to inflate or to set in setContentView.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I will take a look and wll tell you if it worked.

Comment: You can create a new one and put the `WebView` in this. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how! Since `AlertBuilder` will always take the whole `View` given hence lets get the device size first so that to make it possible not to vary with device sizes. This method will return device size in terms of an `array` of `int`. define this in your `activity` .

```
private int[] getScreenSIze(){
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int h = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int w = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    int[] size={w,h};
    return size;
}
```

If you are int a fragment consider chaning one line in the method into

```
getActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
```

if you are in activity ignore the line.

And when the user clicks option item selected We are going to set the height and width of our `webview` as 70% device height and 80% device width and since the `webview` is in Alert Builder. Alert Builder will expand the cover the `webView` as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_inner_basics) {


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 

        int[] screenSize= getScreenSIze(); //This is the method above remember
        int width=screenSize[0];
        int height=screenSize[1];

        int webViewWidth=(int)(0.8*width); //Casting to make them int
        int webViewHeight=(int)(0.7*height);

        android.webkit.WebView wv = new WebView(this);

        wv.setMinimumHeight(webViewHeight);
        wv.setMinimumWidth(webViewWidth);

        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");

        builder.setView(wv);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
       builder.show();
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I hope it works you can control the height and width as you wish to Appear by chnaging 0.7 and 0.8. Happy Coding!

Comment: Its better you change the size of webView during its creation than getting the whole device window during creation.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. Even if I change width to 0.1 , nothing changes. It remains at the same size.

Comment: Ooh I forgot you were using a framework alert dialog while I continue with AlertBuilder. I have edited the answer. Now it will work! I have used the alert builder fully. Its faster than a pre-made alert dialog!

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to show your content in a new activity with the style `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog`

Comment: Is there a way doing it without creating any new activity rather than layout? Isn't it possible to set the size of AlertDialog by using methods which come from AlertDialog.Builder