# AlertDialog properties related to bottom is not working properly with RelativeLayout nor ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-constraintlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data></data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">
        
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@color/my_color"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
<layout>
```

Left image is from XML, but after launching the application, the dialog shows incorrectly. I guess this acts like the ConstraintLayout's height is `wrap_parent` and can't detect the bottom.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: try [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306503/how-to-make-an-alert-dialog-fill-90-of-screen-size). If you are using Custom View already better Go for `DialogFragment` or `Dialog` . `AlertDialog` is a special purpose dialog suitable for only alerts. you can same thing with `AlertDialog` because its a dialog indeed .

Comment: are you using `requireContext()` for your `AlertDialog.Builder` context or just using `null`?

Answer (score 0):

on YourDialog class, you can set dialog width and height,like this.

```
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        dialog?.let { dia ->
        dia.window?.let { win ->
            val attributes = win.attributes
            attributes.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            attributes.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            win.attributes = attributes
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your View is not a dialog. Use `DialogFragment` and set this

```
val params = window.attributes
params?.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
params?.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
params?.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
window.attributes = params
```